# Combining resultsets

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I need to combine two resultsets:

```
--Resultset from Procedure 1
Date    Session Attendees
2013-04-09  Morning 2
2013-04-09  Noon    6

--Resultset from Procedure 2
Session Admitted
Morning 1
Noon    3
```

I need to combine resultset from both the procedures. Please suggest some ways, so that the final resultset should look like:

```
--Date  Session Attendees   Admitted
2013-04-09  Morning 2   1
2013-04-09  Noon    6   3
```

I'm trying this way but it's not working. Please correct me:

CREATE PROCEDURE test1_test2_combine()

BEGIN

```
 DECLARE @tmp_proc1 TABLE
 DECLARE @tmp_proc2 TABLE

  Call test1() ;
 INSERT INTO @tmp_proc1 
  Call test2() ;
 INSERT INTO @tmp_proc2


 Select @tmp_proc1.*, @tmp_proc2.Admitted from @tmp_proc1, @tmp_proc2
 Where @tmp_proc1.rownum = @tmp_proc2.rownum;
```

END

Basically what I'm trying to do is, getting resultset from two procedures and inserting into two temp tables and combining them using rownum. Please advise. Thanks in advance, Krishna

Answer (score -1):

To get the required resultset, you need to join these primary resultsets. Which means, you might think of something like :

```
SELECT * FROM (CALL test_select_users) AS 'result1'
```

JOIN WITH this:

```
SELECT * FROM (CALL test_select_users) AS 'result2'
```

But, **this is not possible.** 
Instead, you can use a [***User-defined function***](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-function.html) or a [view](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-view.html) instead of a procedure.

**A procedure can return multiple result sets, each with its own schema. It's not suitable for using in a SELECT statement.**